# Error retrieving files from a directory

Tags: c#

I have a line of code in my asp.net c# application like this:

```
string a[]=Directory.GetFiles(TextBox2.Text);
```

which is called when a button is clicked. I'm getting an error, "the given path's format is not supported". When I hover over TextBox2, I see a path which looks perfect. Any ideas?

Comment: And what is the path?

Comment: You should check the encoding of the path (Especially if there are special characters)

Comment: If you are using a UNC path, you'll need to use $ in place of colons.

Comment: You should also check if the directory exists first.

Comment: Can you provide some detail on the actual exception (I assume it's an exception) that is being thrown? Also, see here for details of what the various exceptions thrown by `Directory.GetFiles` actually mean: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.... I am betting it's ArgumentException and its because the path contains an illegal character - perhaps this is a network path?

Comment: Also, you need to escape any \ characters (common in Windows paths)

Comment: @LordTakkera The OP is talking about user-provided input in a GUI…

Comment: @OndrejTucny, I know. I am supposing that the user entered text containing \ characters that may need to be escaped. Do these come in escaped from TextBoxes?

Comment: @LordTakkera Escaping is a matter of the syntax of string literals, not user-supplied input.